# View ASP.NET website developed on a VM in safari on Mac

Tags: macos, network, safari, development, vmware

For school I need to make some assignments in ASP.NET on windows. I Have a MBPR with OS X 10.10 and Windows 8.1 (VMWare) running on it. When I run my project in visual studio, google chrome is opened in Windows. This is not a problem, but I want to view my result in safari (Mac). When I enter the IP address and port (192.168.70.140:1102) I should go to the homepage, but instead I see an error message "Invalid hostname".
[image: Bad Request in safari]

Is it possible to view my website created on windows with safari on my Mac?
I would like to keep a dynamic IP for my mac, but it's not a problem to make a static ip when needed.

The following images are screenshots of my network settings:
[image: Network settings Mac (1)]
[image: Network Settings Mac (2)]
[image: Network Settings Windows]
[image: Network Settings VMWare]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. Provide your network settings for VMWare Image, Windows 8, and OS X. I use VMWare Fussion **Pro** to use virtual network features. I generally add a virtual network with static IP's for communications between the Mac & the VM(s), and use the dynamic "real" network for Internet access.

Comment: @LeeJoramo , I added screenshots of my network settings

Answer (score 1):

**I don't have time to test all of this, I use a different and more complicated setup for the Linux servers I run. I also use the vmnet option from the "Pro" version and not the "Private to My Mac". Let me know if this works**

Shutdown your Windows VM

You want to create a new network card in VMWare's settings for the Window's VM. In VMWare's settings for the VM, click "Add Device..." and add a second "Network Adaptor". This is just like adding a network card to a computer. You want this network to be a custom "Private to My Mac".

Start up your Windows VM, it should automatically detect new hardware. Otherwise, force Windows to install the drivers. You may need to have VMWare update its tools.

Get the IP address for Windows is using for the new network adaptor. This address should be accessible to your Mac.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working, I get the same error message (Bad Request)

Comment: Ok, change the VMWare settings for the new Network Adaptor from "Private to My Mac" to "Bridged" with "Auto detect".

Comment: The downside of Bridged is that the Windows system will now be directly on the same network as the Mac. The IP address will change as it gets reset by the network's DHCP server. And other problems can happen when you are on a controlled network.

Comment: Nope, still the same error. Also tried to switch to "Bridged" with "Wi-Fi"

Comment: Assuming that WiFi is a standard device. (Not on an enterprise network that might add lays of security filtering, "Bridged" should work. (although it will be inconvenient when the IP address change.) Make sure the "Bridged" adaptor is properly setup in Windows. I don't know if other adjustments need to be done within Windows to get your ASP.NET to respond to requests on that adaptor.

Comment: Well thanks for my help, I will search if some settings with ASP.NET need to be changed or otherwise I'll go to my teacher and ask for help